Are these quotations an example of inconsistencies in Islamic scholarship with regards to women and hijab?
عن نافع ، عن ابن عمر ” أنه كان إذا اشترى جارية كشف عن ساقها ووضع يده بين ثدييها و على عجزها
Translation: Nafe’e narrated that whenever Ibn Umar wanted to buy a slave-girl, he would inspect her by analysing her legs and placing his hands between her breasts and on her buttocks”
نا علي بن مسهر عن عبيدالله عن نافع عن ابن عمر أنه إذا أراد أن يشتري الجارية وضع يده على أليتيها وبين فخذيها وربما كشف عن ساقها
‘Naf’e reported when Ibn Umar wanted to buy a slave-girl he would place his hand on her buttocks, between her thighs, and may uncover her legs
I believe all these reports seem to point to a major contradiction because scholars stated muslim women needed to cover to prevent fitnah but allowed slave women to be uncovered and touched in the marketplace by random men

What contradiction? What scholars? You can't just lump "scholars" together as one homogenous mass of people who agree on everything ever, and then quote a random narration and call your personal interpretation of it a contradictory scholarly view, that's not how Islamic scholarship works at all.

Questions are not meant for making statements about what you believe. Exceptions are not contradictions. Scholars allowed only potential buyer to see the slave whom he is buying - because of necessity similar to how it is permissible for a prospective husband to look at a woman when he is proposing marriage, or for a doctor to look at his patient. Otherwise the permission of looking at slaves is strictly conditional to having safety from fitnah and sexual desire. Scholars have noted this condition for e.g. here, here.
